# "Linearizing" the factorization problem?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, proof-verification

### Background & Question

I have a different way of approaching the factorization problem: Given $c$ such that $a<b$ and $ab =c$, find $a$ and $b$ where $a$ and $b$ are **distinct primes**.

$$ \underbrace{-\text{Res}( \frac{(\text{cot}(\pi c! c^{-s})- \text{cot}(\pi c^{-s}))}{s^w},0)}_{f(c,w)}  = \underbrace{\sum_{1\leq r \leq  a}  \frac{1}{r^w}}_{g(a,w)} + \underbrace{\sum_{\kappa | c!}\frac{1}{\ln_c(\kappa)^w}}_{k(c,w)}$$

where $w>1$.

Does this "linearize the problem" in the sense one gets $f(c,w) = g(a,w) + k(c,w)$ where $f$,$g$ and $k$ are functions in the above equations? Are there other functions which accomplish the same $ f(c,w) = g(a,w) + k(c,w)$ without the variable $b$? While calculating the exact value of $c!$ is hard will Stirling's approximation provide a range of the value of $a$?

### Rough Sketch of Idea

Consider the following fact:

$$ \frac{c!}{c^a} = \text{Integer} $$

$$ \frac{c!}{c^{a+1}} \neq \text{Integer} $$

Now consider the following contour integral around the origin of radius $R \to \infty$:

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint \frac{(\text{cot}(\pi c! c^{-s})- \text{cot}(\pi c^{-s}))ds}{s^w} = \sum_{s}\text{Res}( \frac{(\text{cot}(\pi c! c^{-s})- \text{cot}(\pi c^{-s}))}{s^w},s)$$

For $w >1 $ the contour vanishes. Note the residues with the exception of $0$ are all single poles can be expressed as:

$$ -\text{Res}( \frac{(\text{cot}(\pi c! c^{-s})- \text{cot}(\pi c^{-s}))}{s^w},0)  = \sum_{1\leq r \leq  a}  \frac{1}{r^w} + \sum_{\kappa | c!}\frac{1}{\ln_c(\kappa)^w}$$